# After delete data from table,should I care about the HWM?

Tags: oracle, sql-delete

As one core table on the production DB has 60 million rows data(70 columns), we need backup part of the data and then delete them from the core table.
from now on the data increment for each month is about 20000,
as the pic shows the column with the many blue cells is we prepare to backup and remove from core table this month,and after this, we need just to do one month back up and remove as one blue cell for each column shows.
So here is the questions.

1. After I use delete table from month<=20160331 for this month,about 15 million rows will be deleted, Need I do anything about the High Watermark? need to reduce it?

2.as every month,there will be one month data deleted,so if I do not treat the High Watermark,the HighWatermark will go up until to its limit,right?

3.any other solutions about backup data?

This [image]

Comment: Is your table partitioned? If not, I would highly recommend you do so; if you partition on the column that indicates which and when data is to be dropped, then you ought to be able to just drop the partition, rather than doing a delete. That has the benefit of meaning you don't need to consider the HWM of the other partitions

Comment: hi,@Boneist,the table is not partitioned,So I need to reduce the HWM,right?

Comment: BTW, how to reduce the HWM?when to reduce?The only thing I am sure is we need reduce the HWM after the first delete,but as every month there exists data deletion,we need reduce HWM for every month? Please kindly advise.

Comment: Rather than looking at reducing the HWM every month, I *seriously* encourage you to look at partitioning the table. Assuming your data is being removed based on a date column, you could partition on that column and then it’s a simple matter of dropping (or maybe exchanging, depending on what you mean by “backing up”) the partition in question. Then there’s no need to move the rest of the table data around to reduce the HWM (something that could potentially adversely affect the performance of queries on that table).

Comment: And with partitioning, queries that have a predicate on the partitioned column could benefit from partition pruning (e.g. querying only a single partition rather than the entire table).

Comment: @Boneist Hi，I Have used the partitioned table to test the performance， only one question need to confirm ，drop a partition will reduce the corresponding HWM，Right？

Comment: Excellent work - I assume the performance is much better? Regarding the partition drop and the HWM; the HWM would apply at partition level. So, drop the partition and you need not worry about the HWMs of the other partitions any more than you would worry about the HWMs of any other table after dropping a table.

Comment: @ Boneist ,Yes,performance is much better ,Awesome!!!, Another question, I have partitioned my table to 27 months(by range interval), and we have a SP which used for all 27 months,why this SP is also faster than before?I can understand if use 10 months data,the other 17 months would not be scanned So SP will faster,but when use 27 month data ,why the SP still faster?

Comment: I don't know; it could be that because the data is more organised (i.e. similar data is in a smaller set of blocks rather than in many blocks spread throughout all the table's blocks) your code can perform better. That's just a guess though, since you haven't provided your stored procedure code, table structure, etc etc etc. If you do want to understand why it went faster and you can't work it out yourself, you'd need to raise a new question and provide as much info as you can, including the stored procedure code (a simplified version if possible), execution plans, table structures etc

Comment: @Boneist ，Thanks，need more testing for above confusion，I will raise another question for this question ，Thanks for your help on this issue.